# What ist the Error according to Line Breakpoint and the Message [Method Name] cannot be resolved to a type?

Tags: java, methods

```
package practice;

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class max {

    public int grosser(int a,int b){

        if(a>b){

        return a;

        } else {

        return b;

        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        int a,b;
        System.out.println("Geben Sie zwei Zahlen ein:");

        Scanner s1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        a = s1.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Geben Sie zweite Zahl ein");
        Scanner s2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        b = s2.nextInt();

        max m = new max();

        int g = new grosser(a,b);
        //hier appear the Error Message 
        //Line break pointer 
        //grosser cannot be resolved to a type
hier ist the problem and i don't know how i can make further
please help me

        System.out.println("Größte Zahl:"+g);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

*First*: you have declared `grosser()` as a method so you can't use `new` keyword with it. And *second*: you're calling `grosser()` from `main()` which is `static` method, so `grosser()` should be also declared as `static`.